# Expression Engine navigation and conditionals

Tags: css, navigation, expressionengine, conditional-statements

Thanks in advance for help with this problem. It's an Expression Engine site. I'm having trouble with simple conditionals for navigation, active state. I have placed an active color sate within the styles; however, there appears to be a problem with the "if statements" themselves because when I inspect element, they render in the code (the navigation is embedded).

```
<nav class="group" role="navigation">
    <ul id="nav" class="group">
        <li class="first"><a {if segment_1 == ""} class="active" {/if}  href="{site_url}"><strong>Now</strong></a></li>
        <li><a {if segment_1 == "articles"} class="active" {/if} href="/articles/"><strong>articles</strong></a></li>
        <li><a {if segment_2 == "readings"} class="active" {/if} href="/book-readings/readings"><strong>books</strong></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a {if segment_2 == "readings"} class="active" {/if} href="/shelf/readings"><strong>shelf</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<nav class="group" role="navigation">
    <ul id="nav" class="group">
        <li class="first"><a {if "{segment_1}" == ""} class="active" {/if}  href="{site_url}"><strong>Now</strong></a></li>
        <li><a {if "{segment_1}" == "articles"} class="active" {/if} href="/articles/"><strong>articles</strong></a></li>
        <li><a {if "{segment_2}" == "readings"} class="active" {/if} href="/book-readings/readings"><strong>books</strong></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a {if "{segment_2}" == "readings"} class="active" {/if} href="/shelf/readings"><strong>shelf</strong></a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Just to confirm, you state:

> they render in the code

I had assumed you meant all of them, hence the suggestion of wrapping the variables in quotes and curly brackets. But you're going to have problems with the last 2 conditions as they will always be matched together. If this is actually your problem, then the solution is to compare both segments:

```
        <li><a {if "{segment_1}" == "book-readings" && "{segment_2}" == "readings"} class="active" {/if} href="/book-readings/readings"><strong>books</strong></a></li>
        <li class="last"><a {if "{segment_1}" == "shelf" && "{segment_2}" == "readings"} class="active" {/if} href="/shelf/readings"><strong>shelf</strong></a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks Peter. I haven't fixed the issue yet, but that conflict with last 2 conditionals has helped. With index.php removed the segments should still be the same right?

Comment: Yes, index.php isn't part of the segments, so there or not doesn't change the segment values or numbering. So it's still not working? What happens if you output {segment_1} and {segment_2} as test variables?